# Google Earth Determining zoom level from bounding box

Tags: geospatial, google-earth, computational-geometry, google-earth-plugin

I got a Windows Forms app making use of Google Earth where users can draw a polygon on the map which is used as a geofence.

What I'd like to do is to be able to zoom to the polygon so that it fits nicely on screen with a click of a button. A sort of zoom to fit function.

Finding the centre of the polygon and setting the Google Earth camera to that lat/long is easy.

What I need is an algorithm that takes a bounding box of lats \ longs, screen height \ width and then determines the altitude to set the camera.

Does anyone have this algorithm or know where one can be found?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To "zoom to the polygon" or any other `KmlObject` it is probably easiest to use the [earth-api-utility-library](http://code.google.com/p/earth-api-utility-library/).

See the methods [createBoundsView](http://code.google.com/p/earth-api-utility-library/wiki/GEarthExtensionsViewReference#createBoundsView%28bounds,_options%29), [setToBoundsView](http://code.google.com/p/earth-api-utility-library/wiki/GEarthExtensionsViewReference#setToBoundsView%28%29) and especially [flyToObject](https://code.google.com/p/earth-api-utility-library/wiki/GEarthExtensionsUtilReference#flyToObject%28obj,_options%29)

For example, where `ge` is the `GEPlugin` object and `polygon` is a `KmlPolygon`.

```
var gex = new GEarthExtensions(ge);
gex.util.flyToObject(polygon, { boundsFallback: true, aspectRatio: 1 } );
```

Comment: There are a couple issues with this. First off, to find half the chord length you should use `var dist = r * Math.sin(d / 2)` since the radius is the hypotenuse (not the adjacent side) of the relevant triangle. Second, the average latitude/longitude you use as the center will not be correct in many cases (e.g. across "more than" a hemisphere number line–wise).

Comment: To be fair I never really used it, it is from here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-earth-browser-plugin/mGBMtHUU1FM - I would actually now suggest using the earth-api-utility-library [ http://code.google.com/p/earth-api-utility-library/wiki/GEarthExtensionsViewReference